# Find channel in Netty 4.0.32

Tags: java, netty

How to get target channel from ChannelGroup in Netty 4.0.32? I want to write message to target channel.
I have to implement ConcurrentHashMap to store Channel with generate uuid key? Have some good solution?

Comment: what you mean with get target channel ?

Comment: I mean, ChannelGroup store channels and I want to get a channel by channel id but in Netty 4.0.32 can not do it. Previous version can do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but you can iterate the ArrayList ChannelGroup to find the channel.

```
ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

for (Channel ch : channels) {
    if (Math.abs(ch.hashCode()) == connectionID) {
        /* do something with you channel */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to store the Channel with the id as key in a Map.